# Incrementing number in an object of mongoose array

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, positional-operator

I am trying to increment the number in MongoDB using mongoose. But I start failing right at the query stage. When I `// @ts-ignore` it flows silently with no error but the value doesn't update.

The error it throws out is:  `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'undefined'`

My Schema:

```js
const CartSchema: Schema<Document<ICart>> = new Schema({
    clientID: { type: String, required: true },
    sourceID: { type: String, required: true },
    items: {
        id: { type: Types.ObjectId },
        amount: { type: Number },
        grindHow: { type: String, trim: true },
        grind: Boolean,
        package: { type: String, trim: true },
        price: { type: Number },
        productID: { type: String },
        productName: { type: String },
        totalProduct: { type: Number },
    },
    source: { type: String, required: true },
}, { collection: "carts", timestamps: true });

CartSchema.virtual('cartTotal').get(function() {
    // @ts-ignore
    const self: any = this;
    
    if(self.items && self.items.length) {
        return self.items.reduce((acc: BigNumber, current: any) => acc.plus(current.totalProduct), new BigNumber(0))
    } else {
        return 0
    }
})
```

The way I am trying to implement that is:

```js
const item = await CartModel.findOneAndUpdate({ sourceID: clientID, 'items.id': itemID }, { $inc: { 'items.$.amount': 1 }}).lean({ virtuals: true })
```

I also tried with `updateOne`. I thought maybe it's more flexible.

[image: That's where it highlights it]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`items` is not an array, it is an object. You should access it with `items.amount` and **NOT** with `items.$.amount`. Change your query like this:

```js
const item = await CartModel.findOneAndUpdate({ sourceID: clientID, 'items.id': itemID }, { $inc: { 'items.amount': 1 }}).lean({ virtuals: true })
```

Comment: Actually, it should be an array in my scenario. As far as I know, you just should describe the values in the array in an object notation. So, `Cannot create field 'amount' in element {items: [ { id: ObjectId('61b3a904b1cae85deecf4144'), grind: false, grindHow: null, package: "250", price: 74, amount: 2, productID: "61ac2a1809f47a4cca6498d4", productName: "Кения 4 фильтра", totalProduct: 148 } ]}` That's what I've got when I try to make it this way: `await CartModel.findOneAndUpdate({ sourceID: clientID, 'items.id': itemID }, { $inc: { 'items.amount': 1 }}).lean({ virtuals: true })`

Comment: But in your schema, `items`  is defined as object and not as array.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was in two places there.

The issue with my Schema - I described it as an object (Thanks to @Nenad Milosavlievic)
The correct Schema is (or close to correct. Any hints on Schema are welcomed):

```js
const CartSchema: Schema<Document<ICart>> = new Schema({
    clientID: { type: String, required: true },
    sourceID: { type: String, required: true },
    items: { type: Array },
    source: { type: String, required: true },
}, { collection: "carts", timestamps: true });
```

and another issue with the way I'm querying for the item. I should have converted the string ID into `ObjectId`. I missed that out ...

It should have been like this (plus I need to return the updated value, so I am adding an option `{ new: true }`):

```js
await CartModel.findOneAndUpdate({ sourceID: clientID, 'items.id': Types.ObjectId(itemID) }, { $inc: { 'items.$.amount': 1 }}, { new: true }).lean({ virtuals: true })
```